# Aptana Studio GIT: src refspec master does not match any

Tags: git, aptana, bitbucket

As I find myself developing a pretty complex MVC-based CMS in PHP. I did create an "update" system but I've heard so much about git and SVN so I have spent a few hours trying to figure out how to do this with aptana studio.

I'm using bitbucket.org though. I added my repo thing and I go ahead and "Push" my project. It asks for my password: I type it in. Then I get the error:
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https.//pthowsen@bitbucket.org/pthowsen/dvc5.git'

Maybe I have to use github and not bitbucket?

Anyway. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first push needs to establish a link between your local master and a remote repo (generally called 'origin')

As mentioned in "[Getting git working in aptana on Ubuntu](http://sysadmin.circularvale.com/desktop-config/getting-git-working-in-aptana-on-ubuntu/)", go to a git command-line and type:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Then all your subsequent push from Aptana will work.

Note: that supposes that you have added and committed at least once.
If your repo has just been initialized, there is no commit, and no '`master`' branch yet.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually switched over to using git and I got it working. Kinda difficult still though. I need to do some more reading on how to use it efficiently. I kinda managed to create 2 branches and work off in another direction and then switch back. A bit daunting at first but oh well. Cheers!